# Making an Octagon in Python out of asterisks

Tags: python, ascii-art

I am trying to write a simple code in Python to make an octagon out of *. Here is the code I have so far, but obviously isn't working properly:

```
oct_length = int(input("What is the length of one side? "))
for i in range(oct_length):
    print(' ' * (oct_length - i-1) + '*' * (oct_length + i*2))
for i in range(oct_length-1):
    print('*' * ((oct_length * 2)))
for i in range(oct_length):
    print(' ' * (i+1) + '*' * ((oct_length-i)*2))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give some examples of the expected input/output combinations?

Comment: It's not obvious at all; you should include the output you think is erroneous. (Yes, the burden is on you, not us, to demonstrate the problem with your code.)

Comment: I can't wrap my head around the solution to your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an edit to your solution that should work:

```
oct_length = int(input("What is the length of one side? "))
for i in range(oct_length):
    print(' ' * (oct_length - i - 1) + '*' * (oct_length + i * 2))
for i in range(oct_length - 1):
    print('*' * (oct_length + (oct_length - 1) * 2))
for i in range(oct_length - 1):
    print(' ' * (i + 1) + '*' * ((oct_length - i + 1) * 2))
```

**Example output for an octagon with a side of 6:**

```
     ******
    ********
   **********
  ************
 **************
****************
****************
****************
****************
****************
****************
 **************
  ************
   **********
    ********
     ******
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. Look at the bottom part. All the rows are missing 1 `*` at the end.

Comment: You are right, I've just fixed my solution. Thank you!